# Ear is not built on Jenkins with maven-ear-plugin

Tags: java, maven, jenkins

While executing mvn install on jenkins I get this error:

> [JENKINS] Archiving disabled
>       Waiting for Jenkins to finish collecting data
>       mavenExecutionResult exceptions not empty
>       message : Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-ear-plugin:2.9:ear (default-ear) on
>   project proj-ear: Cannot copy a directory:
>   /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/proj/workspace/proj-lib/target/classes; Did you
>   package/install com.xxx.proj-lib:jar:1.0.6-SNAPSHOT:compile?

Locally everything builds OK. Do you have any idea how to solve this?

Comment: Can you show the pom file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Somehow replacing the order of goals helped:
From

```
mvn install test surefire-report:report
```

to

```
mvn test surefire-report:report install
```